# Solving a 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider
$x''-2x'+x= te^t$

Determine the solution with initial values $x(1) = e,$  $x'(1) = 0.$

I know this looks like and probably is a very easy question, but i'm not getting the right answer when i try and solve putting into quadratic form. Could someone please demonstrate or show me a different method?

Many thanks :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "putting into quadratic form". Maybe if you show us what you did, we could try to spot a mistake.

Comment: well replacing the terms like this so we would get $x^2-2x+1=te^t$ then solve for x

Comment: $x''$ means the second derivative of $x$. $x^2$ means the second power of $x$. Are you suggesting these are the same thing, so you can replace the one with the other? and replace $x'$ with $x$? and $x$ with $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a tricky problem because the right-hand side is a solution of the left-hand side set to zero (the homogeneous solution).

The homogeneous solution $x^{(H)}$ is

$$x^{(H)}(t) = A e^{t} + B t e^{t}$$

This is because the characteristic equation has $1$ as a double solution, so we have to put a secular component $t$ onto one of the solutions.

This makes finding the particular solution $x^{(P)}$ difficult because it is a solution to the homogeneous equation.  The way around this is to assume that

$$x^{(P)} = C t^3 e^{t}$$

and solve for $C$:

$$6 C t e^{t} = t e^{t} \implies C = \frac{1}{6}$$

Then solve for $A$ and $B$ using the initial conditions.

Comment: this looks similar to something i tried earlier which gave me $x(t)=1/6e^t(t^3-9t+14)$ is this correct?

Comment: @user67411: that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

First we solve the complementary homogeneous equation $x'' - 2x'+x=0$ by presuming a solution of the form $x=e^{rt}$ to yield:

$$e^{rt}\left(r^2-2r+1\right)=0\\(r-1)^2=0$$

So we have repeated roots of our characteristic polynomial yielding a complementary solution $x=c_1e^{t}+c_2te^{t}$.

Recognize that the right hand side of our nonhomogeneous part is not linearly independent to our general solution; we can assume a sufficiently large power of $x$, however, in our particular solution to remedy this.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\on{x}''\pars{t} -2\on{x}'\pars{t} + \on{x}\pars{t} = t\expo{t}}\,,\qquad
\begin{array}{c}
\mbox{Initial Conditions}
\\
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\on{x}\pars{1}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\expo{}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{\on{x}'\pars{1}} & \ds{=} & \ds{0}
\end{array}\right.\end{array}}$

---

- $\ds{\pars{\totald{}{t} - 1}\
  \overbrace{\pars{\totald{}{t} - 1}
  \on{x}\pars{t}}^{\ds{\on{y}\pars{t}}}\ =\ t\expo{t}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\totald{\bracks{\expo{-t}\on{y}\pars{t}}}{t} = t
\\[2mm]
&\expo{-t}\on{y}\pars{t} = {1 \over 2}\,t^{2} + a \implies
\on{y}\pars{t} =
{1 \over 2}\,t^{2}\expo{t} + a\expo{t}\,\quad a = \mbox{constant} 
\end{align}

---

- $\ds{\pars{\totald{}{t} - 1}\on{x}\pars{t} =
  {1 \over 2}\,t^{2}\expo{t} + a\expo{t}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\totald{\bracks{\expo{-t}\on{x}\pars{t}}}{t} =
{1 \over 2}\,t^{2} + a
\\[2mm] &\
\expo{-t}\on{x}\pars{t} = {1 \over 6}\,t^{3} + at + b\,,\quad b = \mbox{constant}
\\[2mm] &\
\on{x}\pars{t} = \pars{{1 \over 6}\,t^{3} + at + b}\expo{t}
\\[2mm] &\
\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcl}
\ds{\expo{}a} & \ds{+} & \ds{\expo{}b} & \ds{=} &
\ds{{5 \over 6}\,\expo{}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{2\expo{}a} & \ds{+} & \ds{\expo{}b} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\,{2 \over 3}\,\expo{}}
\end{array}\right.
\\[2mm] &\ \implies a = -\,{3 \over 2}\ \mbox{and}\
b = {7 \over 3}
\\[5mm] &\
\bbx{\on{x}\pars{t} = {1 \over 6}\pars{t^{3} -
9t + 14}\expo{t}} \\ &
\end{align}